# How to optimize this Javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
Function_Dataset_A_D() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
    var source = ss.getSheetByName("value");
    var lrS = source.getLastRow();
    var rangeSourceA = source.getRange(2,1,lrS,4);
    var catA = rangeSourceA.getValues();
    var target = ss.getSheetByName("dataset");
    target.getRange("A2:D").clearContent();
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        var avals = target.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length+1;
        target.getRange(avals, 1, catA.length, catA[0].length).setValues(catA);
    }
};
```

I would like to optimize this code to run in shorter amount of time. I think the loop part is the main issue.

Comment: google apps script is not javascript

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski kind true (though GAS is built on JavaScript), but the optimization most of the times is related to JavaScript. See solution below, you can store values in an array and use the array instead of each value separately. This can be achieved using JavaScript. Although I do agree the title should be GAS function instead of JavaScript. The solution is not far away from the current title though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose that the values of `catA` are put to an array for 30 times. And, the array is put to the Spreadsheet. By this, I think that the process cost might be reduced.
- By the way, in your script, `var rangeSourceA = source.getRange(2,1,lrS,4);` is used. In this case, the empty row is added to the next rof of the last row.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function Function_Dataset_A_D() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("value");
  var lrS = source.getLastRow();
  var rangeSourceA = source.getRange(2,1,lrS - 1,4);  // Modified
  var catA = rangeSourceA.getValues();
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("dataset");
  target.getRange("A2:D").clearContent();
  
  // I modified below script.
  var ar = [];
  for(i=0; i < 30; i++){
    ar = ar.concat(catA);
  }
  target.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)